# How to convert C++ implementation of GLCM into Java?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, glcm

I got the following snippet [from GitHub](https://github.com/rahul411/GLCM-parameters-using-Opencv-Library) to compute the gray level co-occurrence matrix (GLCM) through OpenCV:

```c++
float energy=0,contrast=0,homogenity=0,IDM=0,entropy=0,mean1=0;
int row=img.rows,col=img.cols;
Mat gl=Mat::zeros(256,256,CV_32FC1);

//creating glcm matrix with 256 levels,radius=1 and in the horizontal direction 
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<col-1;j++)
       gl.at<float>(img.at<uchar>(i,j),img.at<uchar>(i,j+1))=gl.at<float>(img.at<uchar>(i,j),img.at<uchar>(i,j+1))+1;   

// normalizing glcm matrix for parameter determination
gl=gl+gl.t();            
gl=gl/sum(gl)[0];
```

The code above is in C++. I need to convert this into Java but I'm stuck in this line:

```
gl.at<float>(img.at<uchar>(i,j),img.at<uchar>(i,j+1))=gl.at<‌​float>(img.at<uchar>‌​(i,j),img.at<uchar>(‌​i,j+1))+1;
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: i cant convert this lie

Comment: gl.at<float>(img.at<uchar>(i,j),img.at<uchar>(i,j+1))=gl.at<float>(img.at<uchar>(i,j),img.at<uchar>(i,j+1))+1;

Comment: here is the link of complete code [link] (https://github.com/rahul411/GLCM-parameters-using-Opencv-Library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation of a `256x256` symmetric gray level co-occurrence matrix of image `img` (of class `Mat`) corresponding to an offset "one pixel to the right" may be implemented in Java through OpenCV as follows:

```java
Mat gl = Mat.zeros(256, 256, CvType.CV_64F);
Mat glt = gl.clone();

for (int y = 0; y < img.rows(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img.cols()-1; x++) {

        int i = (int) img.get(y, x)[0];
        int j = (int) img.get(y, x + 1)[0];

        double[] count = gl.get(i, j);
        count[0]++;
        gl.put(i, j, count);
    }
}

Core.transpose(gl, glt);
Core.add(gl, glt, gl);
Scalar sum = Core.sumElems(gl);
Core.divide(gl, sum, gl);
```

There is a good bunch of publicly available libraries to compute GLCMs and extract Haralick features from them in Java, for example [GLCM2](https://github.com/cmci/GLCM2), [JFeatureLib](https://github.com/locked-fg/JFeatureLib), etc.

Comment: gl = gl + gl.t();


gl = gl/Core.sumElems(gl)[0];


sir these two line gives me error can you plz help me

the error is 

1st line:
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Mat


2nd line:

The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Scalar

Comment: Fixed and tested

Comment: Done Sir thank you sorry i was newbie to stack overflow i dint know about the green tick sir now i came to know its done sir thank you for sorting me out in this problem