# Initialize the values into Mat object in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, mat

I need to initialize these array values directly into a `Mat` object. I tried using `obj.put(i,j,data)` but this does not work and the `Mat` object is still empty. i need this in java

```
data [] = {103547.0, 2.0959531E7, 5.152769223E9, 1.415924406121E12, 2.0842905E7, 
           4.195143491E9, 1.025510364741E12, 5.000561607E9, 9.99289545049E11, 
           1.332451366923E12}
```

Can explain to me me how to initialize a `new Mat` object where I directly insert the array data?

Comment: which programming language?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but I'm going to assume you are trying to load a `float array` into a OpenCV `Mat` object in a single row. First of all, be sure to check the documentation on constructing a `Mat` in `C++`. Since you have a 1D array and (I assume) you know the `rows` and `columns` you want to give your `Mat`, you should use [this constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a):

```
cv::Mat::Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void * data, size_t step = AUTO_STEP)
```

Here's a code example:

```
float data[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
cv::Mat your_matrix = cv::Mat(1, 10, CV_32F, data);

cout << your_matrix.at<float>(0,2) << endl;
cout << your_matrix << endl;
```

It will output:

```
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Of course you can change the datatype according to your needs (e.g. use `int` instead of `float`). You can ignore the `AUTO_STEP` parameter, but be sure to check the documentation on the usage if you want to use it. Also, if you want to change the structure of your `Mat` (e.g. split the array into multiple rows) you can achieve this by changing the `rows` and `cols` arguments in the constructor:

```
float data[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
cv::Mat your_matrix = cv::Mat(2, 5, CV_32F, data);

cout << your_matrix.at<float>(1,2) << endl;
cout << your_matrix << endl;
```

It will output:

```
8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5; 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You have now split your `Mat` object into two rows of 5 columns, instead of 1 row of 10 columns.

**In case of Java:**
If you want to do this in Java, you were already on the right track. However, you probably forgot to specify the rows, columns and channels/depth. Change the rows, cols and CvType according to whatever suits your data as before. You can do the following:

```
float data[] = new float[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Mat mat = new Mat(1, 10, CvType.CV_32F);
mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Be sure to check the [Java documentation on Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) as well!

Comment: Sorry sir for misleading you i need it in java i saw this method but i am unable to do it in java the constructor is not taking the data as argument in java

Comment: OK no problem, it's pretty similar (at least the logic is). I added some extra code to make it clear for you, hope this helps!

Comment: thankyou sir yes i have forgotten to add channels/depth Cvtype.CV_32F  Working perfect Thankyou sir

Comment: Sir i have another question i am struggling to perform glcm in opencv java searched a lot got no reference and i got come snippets in c++ could u plz take a look at once sir
my problem link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172339/opencv-glcm-c-to-java

Comment: Its important to remember if doing so, the Mat class will point to the memory of data[].
Hence, if assigning another Mat to this dataset, they will share the same memory.
I am missing a copyTrue flag in this constructor.

Answer (score 31):

Try inline initialization if you want to hardcode those values.:

```
// For small matrices you may use comma separated initializers:

Mat C = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0);
cout << "C = " << endl << " " << C << endl << endl;
```

stolen from

http://opencvexamples.blogspot.de/2013/09/creating-matrix-in-different-ways.html?m=1

use data array as source as shown in some else's answer if you want to use a (maybe dynamic) array as input.

Comment: One can use `Mat1d` instead of `Mat_<double>`. Also, do not forget the parenthesis around `Mat_` expression to cast it to `Mat`, otherwise it will always yield an error.

Answer (score 2):

Next, you can do:

```
cv::Mat newMat(i,j,CV_32F,data);
```